# How Auto resize 4 different width images across page according to screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have 4 images across the page (inside a wrapper div) and want them to resize according to the screen size/width.
The usual way would be something like setting css:

```
img {
    max-width: 25%;     /* i.e. each pic = 1/4  */
    height: auto;
}
```

which would make image sizes flexible (i.e. shrinking them on smaller screens).

But my 4 images are different widths, (however their heights are all 200px)
So if I use above technique their displayed heights vary according to their various widths (which I don't want).

I could Photoshop all 4 images into one large one, but would prefer a css solution as it would make any later site picture changes easier.

----------Later Edit:-----------------

I'll try to show the issue better...

[image: the 4 images displayed on a wide screen]

[image: the 4 images displayed on a narrow screen]

First are the 4 images displayed on a wide/normal screen.
2nd is what happens when displayed on a narrow screen.  i.e. the height of the widest pictures get reduced (as well as their width).

I want the whole of the wrapper div to shrink in height (when it reduces in width due to being displayed on a narrow screen) - and the images within the div to shrink in height to match that on the shrunk div.

Comment: could you not set the max/min and height to 200px and set the width to auto and max-width 25% etc basically play with the height.  You could also look at the css background-size options

Comment: Thanks 4 your help - I didn't know about 'background-size' contain/cover. Couldn't get it to solve this issue, but they will solve something in the future ;-)
Meantime min&max to 200px didnt solve, but I've added some images to the post to better explain my issue.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your images in a div and style the div with width:25%,

and images should be

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but No, by itself it doesn't.   
I've added some images to the post to try to better explain my issue.